# Unable to draw matches between the images

Tags: opencv

After picking the region of interest from the sample image. I am trying to match with another image in the dataset. The code below is compiling without error but unable to draw any matches. I have gone through a lot of websites to find any error. Maybe I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define LEFT_NAME "%s\\left%05d.png"
#define OPTICAL_NAME "%s\\track_%05d.png"

#define PATH_V_L "C:\\OpenCV32\\SequenceLeftCamera"//Left images
#define PATH_O_L "C:\\OpenCV32\\SequenceLeftCamera\\Tracking"//Tracked images

#define START_IMG        462
#define END_IMG          170
#define MAX_FN           128

Rect cropRect(0, 0, 0, 0);

void checkBoundary(int &x, int &y, int &width, int &height, Mat img) {
//check croping rectangle exceed image boundary
if (width>img.cols - x)
    width = img.cols - x;

if (height>img.rows - y)
    height = img.rows - y;

if (x<0)
    x = 0;

if (y<0)
    y = 0;
}

char dphw_buffer[MAX_FN];
static char * makeFileName(char *prefix, char *format, int index) {
sprintf_s(dphw_buffer, MAX_FN, format, prefix, index);
return dphw_buffer;
}

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
char *fn1, *fn2;
fn1 = makeFileName(PATH_V_L, LEFT_NAME, START_IMG);
Mat img_object = imread(fn1);
imshow("Original Image", img_object);

cropRect.x = 563;
cropRect.y = 90;
cropRect.width = 41;
cropRect.height = 135;

Rect scene_rectangle = cropRect;

Mat iobject = img_object(cropRect);
imshow("Test", iobject);
cvWaitKey(10);

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using AKAZE Detector
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = AKAZE::create();
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;
detector->detect(iobject, keypoints_object);    

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = AKAZE::create();
Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
extractor->compute(iobject, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);

//-- Opening a text file
ofstream myfile("ORB_detector.txt");
myfile << "ORB Detector keypoints.\n";

int minX, minY, maxX, maxY;

for (int i = START_IMG + 1; i < 487; i++) 
{
    printf("\n\nTracking frame %d \n\n", i);
    fn2 = makeFileName(PATH_V_L, LEFT_NAME, i);
    Mat img_scene = imread(fn2);

    scene_rectangle.x = scene_rectangle.x - 10;
    scene_rectangle.y = scene_rectangle.y - 10;
    scene_rectangle.width = scene_rectangle.width + 5;
    scene_rectangle.height = scene_rectangle.height + 5;

    checkBoundary(scene_rectangle.x, scene_rectangle.y, scene_rectangle.width, scene_rectangle.height, img_scene);      

    scene_rectangle = Rect(scene_rectangle.x, scene_rectangle.y, scene_rectangle.width, scene_rectangle.height);
    Mat iscene = img_scene(scene_rectangle);

    imshow("New Scene", iscene);
    cvWaitKey(10);

    if (!img_object.data || !img_scene.data)
    {
        std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
    }

    detector->detect(iscene, keypoints_scene);
    cout << "Scene Keypoints " << keypoints_scene.size() << "\n";

    extractor->compute(iscene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);
    cout << "Scene Descriptors " << descriptors_scene.size() << "\n";

    //-- Writing the keypoints size to the text file
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile << keypoints_scene.size();
        myfile << "\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using Brute Force matcher
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");       
    matcher->match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);

    cout << "Matches " << matches.size() << "\n";

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;
    cout << "Good Matches " << good_matches.size() << "\n";     

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);     
        }           
    }

    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(iobject, keypoints_object, iscene, keypoints_scene, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), std::vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
    imshow("All good matches", img_matches);        

    //-- Localize the object
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_pts;

    minX = scene_rectangle.x;
    minY = scene_rectangle.y;
    maxX = 0;
    maxY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(keypoints_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene_pts.push_back(keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);

        if (keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.x < minX)
            minX = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.x;

        if (keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.y < minY)
            minY = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.y;

        if (keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.x > maxX)
            maxX = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.x;

        if (keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.y > maxY)
            maxY = keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt.y;
    }

    scene_rectangle.x = minX;
    scene_rectangle.y = minY;

    if (maxX - minX > 0)
        scene_rectangle.width = maxX - minX;

    if (maxY - minY > 0)
        scene_rectangle.height = maxY - minY;

    if (scene_rectangle.width < 100)
        scene_rectangle.width = 100;

    if (scene_rectangle.height < 200)
        scene_rectangle.height = 200;

    if (good_matches.size() > 3) 
    {
        Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene_pts, CV_RANSAC);

        //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
        std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
        obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(iobject.cols, 0);
        obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(iobject.cols, iobject.rows); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, iobject.rows);
        std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

        perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

        //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

        //-- Show detected matches
        imshow("Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches);
    }
    waitKey(0);
    //return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Not clear - is your code not making any matches, or is it making matches but not drawing them?

Comment: I think the problem was with the image. It was not clear enough. I used another image and the program worked. Thank you.